# Count how often values in a 2D array appear in a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have one 2-dimensional numpy array and another 3D-dimensional array. For each number in the first array I would like to count how often this value or an extremer one appears in the second array (taking the 3rd dimension as comparison vector for each element in the first array). For 0 values the function should return `np.nan` since it's not possible here to decide if 0s should be compared to negative or positive numbers.

**EDIT:** With 'extreme' I mean that positive values in a should only be compared with positive values in b and negative values only with negative values in b.

Example:

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

# this is the 2D array
a = np.random.randint(low=-5, high=5, size=(5, 5))

# for each value in a, count how often this value or an extremer one appears
# in b (taking the last dimension of b as comparison vectors)
b = np.random.randint(low=-5, high=5, size=(5, 5, 5))

# expected result
result = np.array([[2, 2, 1, 1, 2],
                   [0, 1, 1, 3, 3],
                   [1, 3, 2, 2, np.nan],
                   [2, 0, 0, np.nan, 1],
                   [3, 0, 1, np.nan, 3]])
```

Comment: Show the expected result. What do you mean by extremer? What have you tried?

Comment: @MadPhysicist You're right, I did an edit to my post and tried to explain what I mean with 'extreme'.

Comment: (1) You still don't explain what "extemer" means. (2) Your explanation of why you want NaNs makes no real sense. Possibly can be clarified by fixing (1). (3) You don't show any attempt whatsoever to solve this on your own. Please fix

Comment: You're losing valuable information here. You can still count the zeros meaningfully. Also, `nan` can only be placed in floating point arrays, which is very wasteful for a counter. Perhaps you could mark the zeros with a negative number instead or something?

Comment: Yes you're right, the numbers could also be floating points! I just used integers as an example. Ah didn't know that np.nan can only be placed in floating point arrays.

Comment: My answer should cover what the question has now. If you come up with minor changes for the output requirement, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I guess it's still not clear what I mean..The solution should respect the sign of the number in a. For instance if the element in a is -2 and the corresponding vector in b is [-2,-3,1] then the output should be 2 since you can count 2 times are number equal or less than -2.

Comment: Just fixed a bug in the end of my answer. I'm getting the same result as you expect. All I'm saying is that when `a == 0`, you can still count the number of exact matches you find, or perhaps record `-1`, which is an invalid count. That way you don't need to switch to floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all these operations, you will want to transfrom `a` into a 3D array to utilize [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
a3 = a[..., None]
```

You can use [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) to normalize the direction of the extrema:

```
s = np.sign(a3)
a3 *= s
b3 = b * s
```

Now all your extrema are positive, so you can count the number of times something is greater than or equal to the corresponding element of `a3`:

```
result = (b3 >= a3).sum(axis=-1)
```

If you want to set zero elements to `np.nan`, you will first need a floating point array. The simplest way to get one is to specify the dtype in the previous line:

```
result = (b3 >= a3).sum(axis=-1, dtype=float)
result[a == 0] = np.nan
```

This can be written more concisely as:

```
s = np.sign(a)[..., None]
result = (b * s >= a[..., None] * s).sum(axis=-1, dtype=float)
result[a == 0] = np.nan
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using np.count()

This functiom should return what you want.

Comment: Please link to docs of a function called `np.count`. I don't think it exists.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).